# Different transition for each view in same view controller swift?

Tags: swift, layout, transition, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

Hi guys ı am stucked when ı try to present view controller . I split my main view to two views my desire is top view comes with .crossdisolve transition and below view comes with fade in transition . But these are in same view controller.Is this possible
.

Comment: Can you clarify your view hierarchy. You have a view controller which has 2 views inside it ? When you present the view controller you want one view to appear with cross dissolve and another view with fade in ? Are you sure you mean view or view controller ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you try to do it in its simplest form.

You can adapt it with this or if you share a few code examples, I can be more helpful.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var topView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var bottomView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        topView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        bottomView.alpha = 0.0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) { [weak self] in
            self?.topView.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { [weak self] in
            self?.bottomView.alpha = 1.0
        }

    }
}
```